# Is this a bug for postgres jdbc handle timestamp of postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, timestamp

follow this question:
[how to use utc in postgres timestamp with jdbc PrepareStatement parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757700/how-to-use-utc-in-postgres-timestamp-with-jdbc-preparestatement-parameter/32758245#32758245)

now i use

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
```

to upload date value, and

```
tstmp.getTime() - tstmp.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
```

to download value from postgres.

but, date.getTime() is milliseconds from 1970-01-01 of UTC timezone, it's static and not related to client timezone, see below

```
new Date(1443145546920)
Fri Sep 25 2015 09:45:46 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
*Now i change timezone from Beijing/Shanghai to Tokyo*
new Date(1443145546920)
Fri Sep 25 2015 10:45:46 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)
```

look, 1443145546920 should always be *Fri Sep 25 2015 01:45:46 +0000*, never change whatever my client TimeZone is.

so, the right way should is:

```
      client(utc+8)                                   dbserver(utc)
  upload time 1443145546920 without tzoffset 
                                                  write 1443145546920 
  download 
                                                  send 1443145546920
  got 1443145546920 and add client tzoffset 480m
```

but postgres jdbc show me this way:

```
      client(utc+8)       jdbc of pg                  dbserver(utc)
  upload time 1443145546920 + tzoffset 
                      - tzoffset 480m
                                                  write 1443145546920 
  download 
                                                  send 1443145546920
                      + tzoffset 480m
  got 1443145546920 + tzoffset
  manual substract tzoffset
```

Comment: Use the precious title space to describe the purported 'bug'. If such *is* a bug, let it form naturally.

Comment: well, my english is poor, may you give me a brief title about it?

Comment: Please show the table definition too. In particular, are you using timestamp or timestamp with time zone?

Comment: no table, just a test sql: "select to_json(?::timestamp) as a, to_json(current_timestamp::timestamp) as b", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757700/how-to-use-utc-in-postgres-timestamp-with-jdbc-preparestatement-parameter/32758245#32758245. i know timestamp with time zone is better choice, but Javascript dont support Date.setTimezoneOffset, so utc is the only way.

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific